# How to use For Loop in Java to ask user for Input

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

Here is my assignment:

**Write a program that will emulate a cash register. Prompt the user to input the price of three items. Add them together to get a subtotal. Determine the tax (6% ) on the subtotal. Find the total amount of the sale subtotal plus tax. Display the price of each item, subtotal amount, tax amount and final amount.**

I have it done like this:

```
package cashregisteremulator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CashRegisterEmulator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Please enter a price for item number one $");
    double price1 = price.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter a price for item number two $" );
    double price2 = price.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Please enter a price for item number three $");
    double price3 = price.nextDouble();

    double total = ((price1) + (price2) + (price3));
    System.out.println("The subtotal is $" + total);

    double tax = .06;

    double totalnotax = (total * tax );
    System.out.println("The tax for the subtotal is $" + totalnotax);
    double totalplustax = (total + totalnotax);
    System.out.println("The total for your bill with tax is $" + totalplustax);

  }
}
```

However, I need to do this assignment using a loop. Since the prompt asks for only 3 iterations, I thought of using a for loop. So far I have this:

```
package CashRegister;

import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CashRegister {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner askPrice = new Scanner(System.in);  

   for(double i = 0 ; i < 3; i++);  
 {
   System.out.println("Enter a value") ;
   double price = askPrice.nextDouble();



 }
}    
}
```

What do I have to do in order to ask the user for a price three times?

Comment: Why do you ask the user to enter a double, then assign it to `counter` then you set `counter` to be 0?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i = ; i < n; i++)
{
    //ask for value;
    sum += value;
}
```

**update**

in your update this must go into the for loop:

```
double[] amount = new int[3];
for(int i = 0; i < amount.len; i++)
{
    // ask user for value
    amount[i] = value;
}

for(int i = 0; i < amount.len; i++)
{
     // do your calculations and print it.
}

// print the total sums.
```

For the totals you will need extra variables.

Comment: No reason to get overly complicated. If the OP doesn't understand a for loop, they're not going to understand interfaces and collections. Stick with an array (especially since there's a predefined fixed number of iterations).

Comment: Yeah, I just realized it and rewrote it into a simple version as not even an array is needed. :)

Comment: It would go into the for loop. Wether you really need an array depends on how the final list should look like. It definitely would be a good idea to have an array for what the user inputs, and then you can loop over it, and do the individual calculations and printing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write all of your code for you, but this can be easily achieved using a for loop:

```
int numberOfIterations = 3;

// The format of the for loop:
// for (initialize counter; continuation condition; incrementer)
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make three iterations and for such scenario, the best thing to use is a **for loop**. In order to store the user inputs, you need an **array** in which you store the values with the **index** of the current position in the **for loop**.

Take a look at this example I built on your code:

```
double[] price= new double[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++); {
     System.out.println("Enter another ");
     double price[i] = price.nextDouble();
}
```

Later on, you can iterator over the price array, and add all the values:

```
double total = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<price.length; i++) {
    total += price[i];
}
```